# After `apt-get upgrade` mdadm won't auto-assemble RAID at startup

Tags: boot, mount, raid, mdadm

After a simple apt-get upgrade, mdadm won't assemble my intel raid anymore automatically. This leads to fstab entries not being mounted and so the startup fails. I'm dropped into a recovery shell after a minute or so. The problem can be manually fixed each boot by entering:

```
mdadm --assemble -scan
mount -a
systemctl default
```

After that, my system is up and everything is working. The question is, what is going wrong here and how can I fix this so I don't have to do this manually each boot.

I have observed something interesting: the whole internet tells me to use the following command `mdadm --assemble --scan`. This however does not do anything. I have to type `mdadm --assemble -scan` (yes, it's **-** instead of **--**).
Maybe this is some kind of bug introduced by the updated mdadm package? This is a Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 64 bit installation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I ran into [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdadm/+bug/1318351). Unsure why my installation worked that long (this bug is a year old and started on 14.04), but here is the fix:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub.d/dmraid2mdadm.cfg
```

Find the following line

```
        GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT $DMRAID2MDADM_TOAPPEND"
```

and comment it out like this

```
##        GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT $DMRAID2MDADM_TOAPPEND"
```

then run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u && sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and it works again. It may make sense to remove the configuration file at all since the transition from dmraid to mdadm seems fully done on my Ubuntu Gnome 15.05 setup.